# update strategy for existing grails apps

Tags: grails

A grails app will contain, among other things:
1) domain models with various fields and relationships to other models.
2) pre-popluated data (such as roles) which goes into the bootstrap.

V1 gets deployed. users create lots more data (i.e. objects in the DB).

You work on V2, which has updated domain models, and also new data items in the boostrap (e.g. new roles).

How do you deploy V2 without killing V1 data?

Does the bootstrap get run again? how does it know when to run it?  If so, it will overwrite some existing data, as well as add new data.  In this case, does every single item in the the bootstrap need to check if it already exists first to avoid duplication?

How do the schema definitions get updated, and how does it preserve data?

Or do people do all updating by hand by writing separate SQL scripts up add new static data and update schema definitions?

Comment: Look into using the Database migrations plugin. It's designed to address these concerns. http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment to your question, these types of changes are best managed through the use of the "update" `dbCreate` setting in `DataSource.groovy` and the [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).

Unless you have your `dbCreate` set to "create-drop" you won't ever destroy your existing data. However, as you change your domain model you may find yourself beyond what Grails can "update" and that's where the database migration plugin comes in.

The plugin is based on liquibase and will manage applying change sets to your database making sure that they only get applied once (unless you say otherwise). It's a great plugin and worth reading the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/) to fully understand how you can use it.

Comment: I have been experimenting with update.  There is some magic going on. somehow, when I create objects in the bootstrap, and start the app multiple times, I dont get multiple copies, even though I dont check if they already exist, and they are not set to be unique, so it looks like the bootstrap.groovy is NOT being executed. BUT if i add a new object creation, this magically appears in the db, without the existing objects being duplicated. Its also adding columns etc. magically without affecting data. I am amazed.  This feature is hardly documented in the 2 books I read.

Comment: I can promise you that Bootstrap.groovy is being run each time the application starts. As far as why you aren't getting multiple copies of the same domains in your database, I suspect that has to do with the code that is in the Bootstrap.groovy class. I would HIGHLY recommend reading the online documentation. Yes, it's long but it's packed with TONS of awesome information and features you won't find in any of the books.